# Python (recursive?) function with enumerated list is looping through unknown data

Tags: python, sockets, byte, enumerate

I have a python threaded socket that at one point I have a  potentially recursive function  named handleData (not sure if it full fills the criteria for it to be recursive).

```
 def handleData(self, chunk):
    current_chunk = self.last_chunk.get(threading.currentThread(), b'') # not sure thread id is safe to use, will be recycled
    print('Last Chunk:', self.last_chunk.get(threading.currentThread(), b''))
    print('Arg Chunk:', chunk)
    current_chunk += chunk
    print('Start Chunk:', current_chunk)
    #data = enumerate(current_chunk) # Enumerate objs have no len and are not subscriptable (accessible through index positions)
    #print('Enumerated Data:', data)
    hash_dec = 35
    doller_dec = 36
    for idx, x in enumerate(current_chunk):
        print('On idx:', idx, 'Byte', x)
        if x == hash_dec and current_chunk[idx+1] == doller_dec and current_chunk[idx+2] == doller_dec:
            start = idx+3
            end = idx+44
            if end >= len(current_chunk):
                 print('Index out of range')
                 self.last_chunk[threading.currentThread()] = current_chunk[idx:]
                 print('Last Chunk:', self.last_chunk[threading.currentThread()])
                 return
            else:
                record = current_chunk[start:end]
                # do math get values
                print('Printing Values')
                self.printValues(record)
                # need to save last chunk as everything after record
                ##self.last_chunk[threading.currentThread()] = current_chunk[end:]
                ##return
                ## THIS METHOD IS FAST when 48 bytes come in, does not work correctly for larger chunks
                # or recursively call this function but make self.last_chunk = '' before hand
                self.last_chunk[threading.currentThread()] = b''
                if self.record_counter > 50:
                    exit()
                print('Ending Chunk:', current_chunk[end:])
                self.handleData(current_chunk[end:])
                ## Likely gets wasteful when chunks are 48 bytes because it will call itself with \n (110), get returned by the if, have more data again after being called again
```

*Sorry for the endless prints in the code!*

*The if records > 50 is because this recursive function turns into an infinite loop*

Bytes are received by the socket and passed to handleData. So it has a chunk of bytes it does an operation on, if it successfully reads a record of data from the bytes, it passes the remaining unread data back into itself.

What happens is it ends up passing the last byte to itself at which point it should realise there is nothing important here, end the loop and let itself be called by the main socket loop with a new chunk.

But instead it iterates through data that doesnt seem to exist and its the enumerated list that seems to be causing this but I cannot figure out why.

Heres a print outlining everything I have explained:

```
Chunk Length: 96
Last Chunk: b''
Arg Chunk: b'192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Start Chunk: b'192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
On idx: 0 Byte 49
On idx: 1 Byte 57
On idx: 2 Byte 50
On idx: 3 Byte 35
Printing Values
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xff000000
Reader: 5888 Sensor: 87711 Age: 0xff000000 LastAge: 0xff000000 AgeDiff: 0x0 Record: 1
Ending Chunk: b'\x00192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Last Chunk: b''
Arg Chunk: b'\x00192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Start Chunk: b'\x00192#$$\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01V\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
On idx: 0 Byte 0
On idx: 1 Byte 49
On idx: 2 Byte 57
On idx: 3 Byte 50
On idx: 4 Byte 35
Printing Values
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xfe000000
Reader: 5888 Sensor: 87711 Age: 0xfe000000 LastAge: 0xff000000 AgeDiff: -0x1000000 Record: 2
Ending Chunk: b'\x00'
Last Chunk: b''
Arg Chunk: b'\x00'
Start Chunk: b'\x00'
On idx: 0 Byte 0
On idx: 5 Byte 36
On idx: 6 Byte 36
On idx: 7 Byte 0
On idx: 8 Byte 0
On idx: 9 Byte 0
On idx: 10 Byte 0
On idx: 11 Byte 254
On idx: 12 Byte 0
On idx: 13 Byte 0
On idx: 14 Byte 0
On idx: 15 Byte 0
On idx: 16 Byte 0
On idx: 17 Byte 0
On idx: 18 Byte 1
On idx: 19 Byte 86
On idx: 20 Byte 159
On idx: 21 Byte 0
On idx: 22 Byte 0
On idx: 23 Byte 0
On idx: 24 Byte 0
On idx: 25 Byte 0
On idx: 26 Byte 0
On idx: 27 Byte 0
On idx: 28 Byte 0
On idx: 29 Byte 0
On idx: 30 Byte 0
On idx: 31 Byte 0
On idx: 32 Byte 0
On idx: 33 Byte 0
On idx: 34 Byte 0
On idx: 35 Byte 0
On idx: 36 Byte 0
On idx: 37 Byte 0
On idx: 38 Byte 0
On idx: 39 Byte 0
On idx: 40 Byte 0
On idx: 41 Byte 0
On idx: 42 Byte 0
On idx: 43 Byte 23
On idx: 44 Byte 0
On idx: 45 Byte 0
On idx: 46 Byte 0
On idx: 47 Byte 0
On idx: 48 Byte 0
On idx: 4 Byte 36
On idx: 5 Byte 36
On idx: 6 Byte 0
On idx: 7 Byte 0
On idx: 8 Byte 0
On idx: 9 Byte 0
On idx: 10 Byte 255
On idx: 11 Byte 0
On idx: 12 Byte 0
On idx: 13 Byte 0
On idx: 14 Byte 0
On idx: 15 Byte 0
On idx: 16 Byte 0
On idx: 17 Byte 1
On idx: 18 Byte 86
On idx: 19 Byte 159
On idx: 20 Byte 0
On idx: 21 Byte 0
On idx: 22 Byte 0
On idx: 23 Byte 0
On idx: 24 Byte 0
On idx: 25 Byte 0
On idx: 26 Byte 0
On idx: 27 Byte 0
On idx: 28 Byte 0
On idx: 29 Byte 0
On idx: 30 Byte 0
On idx: 31 Byte 0
On idx: 32 Byte 0
On idx: 33 Byte 0
On idx: 34 Byte 0
On idx: 35 Byte 0
On idx: 36 Byte 0
On idx: 37 Byte 0
On idx: 38 Byte 0
On idx: 39 Byte 0
On idx: 40 Byte 0
On idx: 41 Byte 0
On idx: 42 Byte 23
On idx: 43 Byte 0
On idx: 44 Byte 0
On idx: 45 Byte 0
On idx: 46 Byte 0
On idx: 47 Byte 0
On idx: 48 Byte 49
On idx: 49 Byte 57
On idx: 50 Byte 50
On idx: 51 Byte 35
Printing Values
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xfe000000
Reader: 5888 Sensor: 87711 Age: 0xfe000000 LastAge: 0xfe000000 AgeDiff: 0x0 Record: 3
Ending Chunk: b'\x00'
```

I need to change how I pass remaining data back to the function so That I stop sending the last byte of the read record (b'/x00') but i'd rather not do another if statement, any ideas? It needs to pass the remaining data incase there is another record in the current chunk.

*EDIT*
Could this be a memory problem, how do I del an enumerated list created in a for loop statement :( I'll try assigning to var and iterate through it before deleting it.

Comment: Its because its not a recursive function and is frankly a crazy attempt at being recursive :P

Answer (score 0):

This was a recursive programming problem. I just changed it the program to return itself rather than call itself, and have it return true in the base cases (although I don't think the true matters).

I used the module pdb (python debugger) to figure this out, very nice tool!

I ran the code in vim with :!python %
And using pdb.set_trace() to create a break point within the start of the function I can step through each line using n(ext).

This allowed me to see how many times it would return into itself and I realised my problem :)

Here is the fixed code:

```
def handleData(self, chunk):
    pdb.set_trace()
    # Assigns the previous unprocessed byte string to the current_chunk, will be empty byte string if none found
    current_chunk = self.last_chunk.get(threading.current_thread(), b'')
    # Adds the argument chunk to the previous chunk (if called by itself or from main loop)
    current_chunk += chunk
    current_len = len(current_chunk)
    # Decimal values of ASCII chars #, $
    hash_dec = 35
    dollar_dec = 36
    idx = 0

    # For loop to iterate over the byte string
    for x in current_chunk:
        # if current index is # and the next two indexs are $ then we have found a record delimiter
        if x == hash_dec and current_chunk[idx+1] == dollar_dec and current_chunk[idx+2] == dollar_dec:
            # Index positions for list slice
            start = idx+3
            end = idx+45

            # if end slice index is greater than range of list
            if end > current_len:
                print('Index out of range')
                self.last_chunk[threading.current_thread()] = current_chunk[idx:]
                return True

            self.printValues(current_chunk[start:end])

            self.last_chunk[threading.current_thread()] = b''

            #if end == current_len:
                #print('No more bytes left in chunk!')
                #return True

            print('Ending Chunk:', current_chunk[end:])
            return self.handleData(current_chunk[end:])

        idx += 1
```

If anyone has any other ideas for this code I would love to hear them!
The size of the chunk directly relaytes to how many times it may have to return through itself to reach the main loop, so I'm thinking of keeping the socket.recv() on a low byte size (was 4096 - thinking 1024)